# org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: com/itextpdf/text/Document NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, maven, itext, pdfbox, noclassdeffounderror

I keep getting the following error trying to use a PDF lib and not having any luck. I am using spring and maven. I have tried pdfbox and itextpdf.

I get the Following error with either one ( obv the class part is different )
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: com/itextpdf/text/Document
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/itextpdf/text/Document

pom

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itextpdf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.13</version>
        </dependency>
```

Class

```
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;

public enum PDFController {

    INSTANCE;

    PDFController() {
    }

    public void testPDF() {

        // Error happens here
        Document doc = new Document();
    }

}
```

It appears Maven is adding the correct jars. So why can it not find the class?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have it fixed. I am used IntelliJ and under Project Structure -> Artificats -> Output Layout.

My Jars I was adding with Maven were getting added to the "Available Elements" area. I had to move them into the Web-INF/lib folder.